# Multiclass classification with many classes and wide range of sample sizes

Tags: multiclass-classification, text

I'm working on a free text classification problem with over 100 classes in the training data. There is huge variation in the sample sizes of the classes: ranging from 1 to around 6000. I am using a custom-made algorithm which builds a training model of each class's most significant keyword or phrase (up to 3 consecutive words). The significance is a value between 0 and 1 and is the difference in the frequency that the term occurs in the class and the frequency that it occurs among all data not in the class. I'm then using this model to test whether whether new, manually class-labelled records have the correct class by assigning PASS if the new record's class has a significance level > .9 AND the test record's free text contains the keyword/phrase. If its > .9 and lacks the keyword, I'm giving it a FAIL. And if the class significance is <= .9, then I'm giving it a NOT CHECKED, regardless of if the test text contains the keyword or not because the strength of the top keyword is too weakly associated with the class.

I developed this custom-made algorithm after finding that Naive Bayes (a slightly more complicated probabilistic method taking into account all words) wasn't doing that well...I think because of the nature of my data: the text is often short and there are some classes where 100% should contain a specific keyword.

The results so far are promising...far fewer false positives than Naive Bayes. But I've found that classes with tiny sample sizes in the training data had a LOT more false positives than with large sample sizes.

So my question is: what would the best way to account for % confidence based on the sample size?

The best idea I have right now is to use the Sigmoid function, where input x = sample size and output y = something like % confidence, then multiple this Sigmoid output by the significance level described above and only doing the incoming record class check if this modified significance level is > .9. Are there better options?